# branch.io: cannot detect installed app from javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, branch.io

I'm trying to get a basic journey app banner to work. No deep links (at this stage), just a basic banner when the user goes to our web site that allows him to either get our iOS-app, or launch it if it is already installed. 
Problem is that the banner always displays the "get in app store" option, even when the app is already installed on the device.

I have looked at [Branch.io: javascript detect whether mobile app is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41880919/branch-io-javascript-detect-whether-mobile-app-is-installed?rq=1) and other similar questions without any help.

I have run the universal links validator and the ulv_script.sh and it shows no issues.

In the web page I do:

```
branch.init('My_key_live_xxx', null, function(err, data) {
    console.log('init...');
    console.dir(data);
});
```

The data property looks like follows when debugging:

```
{data: "", data_parsed: {}, has_app: null, identity: null, referring_identity: null, …}
```

In the AppDelegate in the ios-app I do nothing besides:

```
let branch: Branch = Branch.getInstance()
        branch.initSession(launchOptions: launchOptions, andRegisterDeepLinkHandler: {params, error in
            if error == nil {
                // params are the deep linked params associated with the link that the user clicked -> was re-directed to this app
                // params will be empty if no data found
                // ... insert custom logic here ...
                print("params: %@", params as? [String: AnyObject] ?? {})
            }
        })
```

I figured no special code is needed here until I actually want to link to a specific place in the app. Right now I just want the app to open (or actually to just be detected since detection is needed for the open button to show...)

The semi-functional, always pointing to app-store, version is live in case someone wants to see the issue upfront: https://www.papereed.com/player

I guess I miss something really fundamental regarding branch.io and hopefully someone can help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to a restriction on Apple's side, when the user taps on a Universal link on the web browser (i.e. Safari), if the link has the same domain as the current web page it does not use Universal linking to open the app but instead opens the link in Safari. You can read more about this behavior [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html).

To overcome this restriction, Branch uses a different domain for the link behind the Deepview button, so that the domain being visited is different from the current web page. The link behind the Deepview button uses the domain of the format '-alternate.app.link'.

Please ensure that you have added the `-alternate.app.link` domain for your app in the entitlements file. You can check the documentation providing information on how to add the domains here.

For the 'Get/Open in App' CTA button update:

This is common during development. Because the app is frequently re-installed on the device, the flag, `has_app`, that Branch uses to determine whether the app is installed on the device goes in a faulty state.

To force reset the `has_app` variable to change the Journey's banner CTA from 'Download' to 'Open', please follow these steps:

1. Click on the Download button - this should redirect tot he Play or App Store
2. Install the app
3. Return to the web page with the Journeys banner, which should still display the Download button
4. Tap on the Download button again - the app should open (once you update the entitlements file to include `-alternate.app.link`) and data specified in the Journeys configuration should be available to the app
5. Close and then re-open the web page with the Journeys banner - the banner should now have an "Open" button
6. Tap on the "Open" button

Please note that the above steps are required only during development mode for testing purposes. Out in the wild in production, users will not see this issue. Also, please note, it might take some time for the CTA button to update. It could be up to 30 minutes during peak hours.

Comment: Thank you, the force reset step you gave worked out! Probably a combo of this and CTA button update delay.